# REST Assured doesn't accept curly brackets

Tags: java, rest-assured

Unable to use query in my Endpoint URL

I have tried using .`queryParams()` but it does not seem to work . I am getting the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters.
>   Expected 1, was 0.Undefined path parameters are:
>   cycle-id[12345];test.name[Validate_REST_Assured_Curly_Brackets].

Can someone help me out

```
almQuery=https://{almurl}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/test-instances?query={cycle-id[12345];test.name[Validate_REST_Assured_Curly_Brackets]}

Response response = RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation()
.contentType("application/xml")
.cookie(cookie)             .get(getEntityEndpoint(almQuery)).then().extract().response();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how RestAssured implementation works. Whenever your url contains curly braces it will expect path param with for that. For example, if your url contains `{project}` you should provide a path param with name `project`.

The only way to avoid it is by manually encoding `{` and `}` characters in your url. You could use [URLEncoder.encode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), but it will mess your other characters so try simply replacing all `{` and `}` with encoded values:

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://www.example.com/path/{project}";
    String encoded = encodeUrlBraces(url);
    RestAssured.given()
        .when()
        .get(encoded);
  }

  private static String encodeUrlBraces(String url) {
    return url.replaceAll("\\{", "%7B").replaceAll("}", "%7D");
  }
}
```

Here's an answer for this from Rest Assured founder and contributor https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/682